# Restoring Resharper after trialing StyleCop - get/set line breaks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, stylecop, resharper-7.1

I'm having trouble getting Resharper's clenaup code to stop changing properties like:

```
    public long Value
    {
        get { return _thingy; }
        set { _thingy = value; }
    }
```

to:

```
    public long Value
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _thingy; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            _thingy = value; 
        }
    }
```

This has been just fine for a long time until today. I tried StyleCop, did not like it, and uninstalled it. After that all my simple properties get expanded.

Not the end of the world but a bit of trouble as I'm managing several branches (another story).

Is there a setting?

I'm using Resharper 7.1 and Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In the resharper options, code editing, C#, Line breaks and wrapping, Other (in the right panel) there's a 'Place simple property/indexer/event declaration on single line' checkbox which is close to what you want.

it shows a sample - unchecked:

```
class C
{
    private int Property
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
}
```

checked:

```
class C
{
    private int Property { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the prompt response ... but I disconnected from the office soon after posting my question (late here) ... i will give it a go tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Got the very similar problem (except I only want {get; set;} to be on the same line, but if something is written in get{}, then on new line) as OP and this doesn't help even though I have this setting checked. Maybe VS is overriding some settings, because resharper settings show how it would be after checking, but it won't happen!

Comment: Actually, yes, I checked the setting in VS Tools->Options->C#->Formatting->Wrapping->"Leave block on single line" and now it is working. Now it works like a charm. Let's say I have `public int Users { get; set; }`. If I hit ctrl+K+D it stays in one line. However, if I hit "enter" at the end of `get;`, and hit ctrl+K+D, it formats in multiple lines. Perfect!